# Miscommunication with repeated fields using gRPC

Tags: node.js, typescript, grpc, proto

I have a client-server setup where the client should be able to receive data from the server. This is the relevant part of the .proto-file:

```proto
rpc GetBufferContents(Empty) returns (BufferData);

message Empty {}

message BufferData {
  repeated sint32 data = 1;
}
```

The client requests this data like so:

```js
async getBufferData(): Promise<number[]> {
    const buffer = await this.service.getBufferContents(new Messages.Empty(), null);
    return buffer.getDataList();
}
```

where `service` is the generated gRPC service.

while the server responds like this:

```js
function getBufferContents(call, callback) {
    // generate some mock data
    const len = 8192;
    let data: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      const single = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / 3000) * 100 + Math.random() * 2;
      data.push(Math.fround(single));
    }
    const contents = {
      dataList: data,
    };
    callback(null, contents);
}
```

The server itself is a simple node.js-server that is defined like so:

```js
import assert from "assert";

function getServer() {
    const server = new Server();
    server.addService(serviceDefinition, {
      getBufferContents: getBufferContents,
    })
    return server;
}

if (require.main === module) {
    const server = getServer();
    server.bindAsync(
      '0.0.0.0:9090', ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), (err, port) => {
          assert.ifError(err);
          server.start();
          console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
      });
}

exports.getServer = getServer;
```

I have successfully transmitted messages from and to the server when they are not repeated. However, I am struggling with repeated messages.
When I change the field `dataList` to `data`, I receive the error
`Error when deserializing response data: undefined`. When I leave it at `dataList`, the received array is defined, but empty. I have checked that the array given to the message object is not empty. Am I missing something here?

I am generating the client code with this command

```sh
protoc -I=. \
    "$PROTO_FILE" \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs:$BUILD \
    --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:$BUILD
```

and the server code using these two commands

```sh
  grpc_tools_node_protoc \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:$BUILD \
    --grpc_out=grpc_js:$BUILD \
    -I=.. \
    "$PROTO_FILE"

  protoc -I=.. \
      --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=../node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts \
      --ts_out=$BUILD \
      -I=.. \
      "$PROTO_FILE"
```

Edit:
What I have tried so far:

- changing the field to a field of `doubles`
- changing the server implementation to a python implementation

The error persists for both options

Answer (score 1):

In your client code, you pass as an argument to the gRPC method by constructing a class, specifically `new Messages.Empty()`, and you used `.getDataList()` to examine that field in the response. However, in your server code you simply create a plain object and pass it to the callback. If the generated protobuf code for the client and server comes from the same generator, only one of those is correct.

The most likely solution is that your server code will need to construct a `Messages.BufferData` and call `setDataList` on that object to properly set the `data` field.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! At first I thought that you were spot on, but unfortunately the error persists. I had mixed dynamic grocery definitions with static definitions (I created the grpc code statically for the client but used the dynamic option for the client). I have now chosen to use static code generation for both client and server and I‘m seeing a similar error - Error Code 13; error during deserializing.

Comment: If you were using the dynamic code generation for the code in the question, `contents = {data: data}` should have worked. And if you're using the same generated code for the client and server now, it shouldn't be possible to have a serialization incompatibility like that. Did you also switch the source of the `serviceDefinition` to come from the statically generated code?

Comment: Yes, I did change the sources. I will update my question with the script that I use to generate the sources; maybe there is some problem with that? What's also weird is that every other request (that doesn't have a repeated field) works just as expected